# How to find rank of order number by same start

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, ranking, ranking-functions

Dok table contains order numbers  :

```
create table dok ( doktyyp char(1),
     tasudok char(25) );
CREATE INDEX dok_tasudok_idx ON dok (tasudok);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dok_tasudok_unique_idx ON dok (doktyyp,tasudok)
WHERE doktyyp IN ( 'T', 'U') ;
```

Order numbers contain same start part and different suffices like

```
91000465663        
91000465663-1
91000465663-2
91000465663-T
91000465663-T-1
```

How to create query which returns order sequence number by given prefix. For doktyyp column value is always constant 'T'.

For numbers below, results should be

```
91000465663        returns 1
91000465663-1      returns 2
91000465663-2      returns 3
91000465663-T      returns 4
91000465663-T-1    returns 5
```

Query

```
with koik as (
select rank() over (order by tasudok), tasudok
from dok 
where doktyyp='T' and tasudok  like '91000465663%'
)

select rank 
from koik 
where tasudok='91000465663-1'
```

Seems to work properly but looks too long for this simple task. How to create shorter and better query ?

Explain output:

```
"Subquery Scan on koik  (cost=685.04..685.07 rows=1 width=8)"
"  Filter: (koik.tasudok = '91000465663-1'::bpchar)"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=685.04..685.06 rows=1 width=34)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=685.04..685.05 rows=1 width=26)"
"              Sort Key: dok.tasudok"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dok  (cost=23.55..685.03 rows=1 width=26)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (doktyyp = 'T'::bpchar)"
"                    Filter: (tasudok ~~ '91000465663%'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dok_tasudok_unique_idx  (cost=0.00..23.55 rows=437 width=0)"
"                          Index Cond: (doktyyp = 'T'::bpchar)"
```

Using postgres 11

Comment: is there an index on column tasudok? What does EXPLAIN say?

Comment: I updated question and added indexes and explain output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your use case correctly, the query will always consider a fixed prefix of the first 11 characters on `tasudok`, so in order to speed things up you can tell the index to sort `tasudok` already truncated to the first 11 characters (partial index), so that you don't need to use like.

```
CREATE INDEX dok_doktyyp_tasudok_idx ON dok (doktyyp, SUBSTRING(tasudok FROM 1 FOR 11));
```

And the query should look like

```
WITH koik AS (
  SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tasudok), tasudok
  FROM dok 
  WHERE doktyyp='T' AND SUBSTRING(tasudok FROM 1 FOR 11) = '91000465663'
)
SELECT tasudok,rank FROM koik 
WHERE tasudok = '91000465663-1';
```

Of course, this would not make sense if the prefix size is variable.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2d8d22ab4401eccdfc39792bef09b0c1)